# Directadmin php.ini disable daylight saving

Tags: php, timezone, centos7, dst, directadmin

I have a problem from php time .
On my centos 7 server I had installed directadmin and I disabled daylight on centos but I dont know how to disable daylight on php.ini .
please help me

I set timezone Asia/tehran in php.ini but i want when use

> php -r "date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran'); echo date('H:i');"

show me current server time.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly about how you "disabled daylight" (by which I presume you mean "disabled daylight saving time", not that you like your room really dark)? PHP gets its time zone data from an installed database, perhaps what you're actually asking is how to update that for Iran's recent policy change?

Comment: Excuse me for my English. In fact, I mean, this is because of the new policy in Iran, how to set the clock in php.ini to display correctly

Comment: Ok, then as I say, this is not about a *setting*, but something you need to *update* on your system. Try searching for "update timezone database".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.